# The given data was not valid JSON in swift

Tags: swift, api

### Api Call

```
@State private var receives = [Advertisment]()
func loadData() async {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://new.demozab.com/armup/api/public/api/dashboard")
    else{
        print("iii")
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.setValue("U45GxRbn6NLY9Q3QomfgdWpePAjnlTE7O05wPIXL", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    do{

        let (data,_) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        print(data.count)
        print("\(data)")
         let decodedResponse =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Dashboardd.self, from: data)

        print("klllll")
        receives = (decodedResponse.data.advertisments )
        print(receives)



    }
    catch{
        print("\(error)")

    }



}
```

### Model Class

```
struct Dashboardd: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: DashboardDataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DashboardDataClass: Codable {
    let quickStats: QuickStats
    let advertisments: [Advertisment]
    let receives: [Receive]
}

// MARK: - Advertisment
struct Advertisment: Codable {
    let id, cryptoCurrencyID, tradeBy: Int
    let tradeType, location, country, market: String
    let margin: String
    let tradePrice: Double
    let tradeTotal, minTransactionLimit, maxTransactionLimit, totalLimit: Int
    let totalTradeAmount, cryptoCoinAmountPrice, paymentWindow: Int
    let paymentMethod, accountDetails, additionalInformation, terms: String
    let isFeedback, status: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt, slug: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case cryptoCurrencyID
        case tradeBy
        case tradeType
        case location, country, market, margin
        case tradePrice
        case tradeTotal
        case minTransactionLimit
        case maxTransactionLimit
        case totalLimit
        case totalTradeAmount
        case cryptoCoinAmountPrice
        case paymentWindow
        case paymentMethod
        case accountDetails
        case additionalInformation
        case terms
        case isFeedback
        case status
        case createdAt
        case updatedAt
        case slug
    }
}

// MARK: - QuickStats
struct QuickStats: Codable {
    let buyCnt, sellCnt, openCnt, pendingCnt: Int
    let completeCnt: Int
}

// MARK: - Receive
struct Receive: Codable {
    let id, tradeOrderID, senderID, receiverID: Int
    let isTrustedUser, isDistrustedUser, feedbackScore: Int
    let message: String
    let status: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt, username: String
    let image: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case tradeOrderID
        case senderID
        case receiverID
        case isTrustedUser
        case isDistrustedUser
        case feedbackScore
        case message, status
        case createdAt
        case updatedAt
        case username, image
    }
}
```

### Json Response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Dashboard details",
    "data": {
        "quickStats": {
            "buyCnt": 3,
            "sellCnt": 0,
            "openCnt": 0,
            "pendingCnt": 0,
            "completeCnt": 1
        },
        "advertisments": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "crypto_currency_id": 7,
                "trade_by": 4,
                "trade_type": "1",
                "location": "mdu",
                "country": "1",
                "market": "5",
                "margin": "15",
                "trade_price": 10,
                "trade_total": 0,
                "min_transaction_limit": 1,
                "max_transaction_limit": 16,
                "total_limit": 16,
                "total_trade_amount": 0,
                "crypto_coin_amount_price": 0,
                "payment_window": 1,
                "payment_method": "a",
                "account_details": "d",
                "additional_information": "d",
                "terms": "mm",
                "is_feedback": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2023-02-15",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T05:31:12.000000Z",
                "slug": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "crypto_currency_id": 1,
                "trade_by": 4,
                "trade_type": "Buy",
                "location": "demo",
                "country": "98",
                "market": "74",
                "margin": "1.2",
                "trade_price": 15375.35,
                "trade_total": 0,
                "min_transaction_limit": 100,
                "max_transaction_limit": 1000,
                "total_limit": 1000,
                "total_trade_amount": 0,
                "crypto_coin_amount_price": 0,
                "payment_window": 15,
                "payment_method": "1",
                "account_details": "demo",
                "additional_information": "demo",
                "terms": "demo",
                "is_feedback": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2023-01-28",
                "updated_at": "2023-01-28T14:42:52.000000Z",
                "slug": "BTC"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "crypto_currency_id": 1,
                "trade_by": 4,
                "trade_type": "Buy",
                "location": "demo",
                "country": "98",
                "market": "98",
                "margin": "1.2",
                "trade_price": 1254583.09,
                "trade_total": 0,
                "min_transaction_limit": 10,
                "max_transaction_limit": 100,
                "total_limit": 100,
                "total_trade_amount": 0,
                "crypto_coin_amount_price": 0,
                "payment_window": 15,
                "payment_method": "1",
                "account_details": "demo",
                "additional_information": "demo",
                "terms": "demo",
                "is_feedback": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2023-01-28",
                "updated_at": "2023-01-28T14:02:46.000000Z",
                "slug": "BTC"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "crypto_currency_id": 3,
                "trade_by": 4,
                "trade_type": "Buy",
                "location": "demo",
                "country": "22",
                "market": "102",
                "margin": "1.2",
                "trade_price": 0.89,
                "trade_total": 0,
                "min_transaction_limit": 10,
                "max_transaction_limit": 100,
                "total_limit": 100,
                "total_trade_amount": 0,
                "crypto_coin_amount_price": 0,
                "payment_window": 15,
                "payment_method": "1",
                "account_details": "demo",
                "additional_information": "demo",
                "terms": "demo",
                "is_feedback": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2023-01-28",
                "updated_at": "2023-01-28T14:00:59.000000Z",
                "slug": "BUSD"
            }
        ],
        "receives": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "trade_order_id": 11,
                "sender_id": 4,
                "receiver_id": 4,
                "is_trusted_user": 1,
                "is_distrusted_user": 0,
                "feedback_score": 4,
                "message": "test",
                "status": 1,
                "created_at": "2023-01-28T14:27:04.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-23T05:23:02.000000Z",
                "username": "smith",
                "image": "https://new.demozab.com/armup/api/public//userpanel/images/profile.svg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### Error is :

dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., })))

Problem in Decode the json response

Comment: could you use `print("\n---> data  \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) \n")` instead of your `print("\(data)")` and show us what it prints.

Comment: well, now you know what you get from the server is not the json data you expect. Can you show the link to the server API documentation.

Comment: I get 500 error, because of header not passed correctly. im passed as     request.setValue("Bearer W9fUlQbgowbUrGhxEbmKRbktCiinBALh2YyJ3dhn",
                         forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") but it wont works

Comment: Is this what the server expect? Can you show the link to the server API documentation.

Comment: this is the documentation          :            Dashboard:
 end-point name: dashboard
 method: GET
 Authorization: Bearer Token 
 response: 
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Dashboard details",
    "data": {
        }
          }

Comment: Can you show the **full url** to the server API documentation, and the full url of the API.
     Seems to me the url you are using maybe the source of the problems.

Comment: the problem is not in the JSON decoding because there is nothing to decode. the server responds with HTTP 500 and a HTML error page.

Comment: use this example code to evaluate the response before trying to actually parse it
`let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)`
`guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {`
`print("Unexpected Response \(String(describing: response))")`
`return`
`}`

Comment: `data(from: url)` -> `data(from: request)`, because you are ignoring the `URLRequest` you created and which has the headers token. When you do `data(from: url)`, it's equivalent to `data(from: URLRequest(url: url))`, ie doing another request totally unrelated to the other one.

Comment: Well spotted @Larme, should really be `URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`
     However this will still not work if the url is wrong, which I believe it is. Note that the struct models are also completely wrong, they do not match the json data. The OP is missing the `enum CodingKeys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example code, using `URLSession.shared.data(for: request)` deduced from @Larme comment,
and the following `corrected` models for the json data decoding. Works well for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var receives = [Advertisment]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(receives){ ad in
            Text(ad.accountDetails)
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }

    func loadData() async {
        let token = "W9fUlQbgowbUrGhxEbmKRbktCiinBALh2YyJ3dhn"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://new.demozab.com/armup/api/public/api/dashboard")
        else {
            print("bad url")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Dashboardd.self, from: data)
            receives = decodedResponse.data.advertisments
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct Dashboardd: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: DashboardDataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DashboardDataClass: Codable {
    let quickStats: QuickStats
    var advertisments: [Advertisment]
    var receives: [Receive]
}

// MARK: - Advertisment
struct Advertisment: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id, cryptoCurrencyID, tradeBy: Int
    let tradeType, location, country, market: String
    let margin: String
    let tradePrice: Double
    let tradeTotal, minTransactionLimit, maxTransactionLimit, totalLimit: Int
    let totalTradeAmount, cryptoCoinAmountPrice, paymentWindow: Int
    let paymentMethod, accountDetails, additionalInformation, terms: String
    let isFeedback, status: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt, slug: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, terms, status, slug, location, country, market, margin
        case cryptoCurrencyID = "crypto_currency_id"
        case tradeBy = "trade_by"
        case tradeType = "trade_type"
        case tradePrice = "trade_price"
        case tradeTotal = "trade_total"
        case minTransactionLimit = "min_transaction_limit"
        case maxTransactionLimit = "max_transaction_limit"
        case totalLimit = "total_limit"
        case totalTradeAmount = "total_trade_amount"
        case cryptoCoinAmountPrice = "crypto_coin_amount_price"
        case paymentWindow = "payment_window"
        case paymentMethod = "payment_method"
        case accountDetails = "account_details"
        case additionalInformation = "additional_information"
        case isFeedback = "is_feedback"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}

// MARK: - QuickStats
struct QuickStats: Codable {
    let buyCnt, sellCnt, openCnt, pendingCnt, completeCnt: Int
}

// MARK: - Receive
struct Receive: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id, tradeOrderID, senderID, receiverID, status: Int
    let isTrustedUser, isDistrustedUser, feedbackScore: Int
    let message, createdAt, updatedAt, username, image: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, username, image, message, status
        case tradeOrderID = "trade_order_id"
        case senderID = "sender_id"
        case receiverID = "receiver_id"
        case isTrustedUser = "is_trusted_user"
        case isDistrustedUser = "is_distrusted_user"
        case feedbackScore = "feedback_score"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

You will need to find from the server docs which fields are optional and adjust the code accordingly, ie add `?` to it.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked, Can u explain me how you created this model class

Comment: Yes, after `let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)` add `print("\n---> data \n \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")`, then copy and paste the resutls
  into `https://app.quicktype.io/` and all the models are generated for you. That simple.